# meaning of the phrase "be of thinking"?

Tags: meaning

I have happened upon it in the online journal [*Psychology Today*](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/lifetime-connections/201804/love-first-sight-maybe-in-hindsight). Here it goes:

> if their priorities don’t allow space for you to pursue your own favorite pastimes, you might want to re-consider the longevity potential of the relationship. Also, ask yourself if you feel good about his choices or **are you already of thinking** of ways that you’d need to “cover” for his behavior?

I can understand what *think of* means, but I cannot get why the preposition *of* was used there.

Comment: It must be a typo. I would omit "of" in "of thinking". By the way, a nice way of saying "I have happened upon" is "**I came across**"

Comment: It is more idiomatic to use the simple past there, since you're describing a particular event that took place.  **I happened upon** or as CowperKettle suggests, **I came across**, or **I found**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text has a mistake.

"are you already of thinking of ways" should be "are you already thinking of ways".